# Dynamic Variables Within Functions

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

Why does this work:

```
function myfunction($v) {
    $query = $v['host'] == '1';
    return ( $query );
}

$output = array_filter($recordset,myfunction);
print_r($output);
```

Whereas this script, which tries to accomplish the same thing with variables, does not?

```
$column1 = 'host';
$value1 = 1;
$query1 = '$v[\''.$column1.'\'] == '.$value1;

function myfunction($v) {
    $query = $GLOBALS['query1'];
    return ( $query );
}

$output = array_filter($recordset,myfunction);
print_r($output);
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `$query = $v['host'] == '1';` doesn't set `$query` to be the expression `$v['host'] == '1'`. It *evaluates* `$v['host'] == '1'` and sets `$query` to the *value* of the expression, which is 1 or 0, depending on whether `$v['host']` is equal to `'1'`.

`$output = array_filter($recordset,myfunction);` works because [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/array_filter) is meant to take a user-defined PHP callback function for its second argument.

Dynamic coding is really only achievable in PHP using the [`eval`](http://www.php.net/eval) function (highly dangerous!) or using an object-oriented structure with [object overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.overload.php).

Answer (score -1):

Can you use global $query1?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I replaced $query = $GLOBALS['query1']; with $query = $query1; the script stopped working entirely.

Comment: Then write `global $query1` at the start of the function.